# set the logged in user to created_by for django CreateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Apart from form_valid() method what are the other efficient ways i can set the user to created by.

**views.py**

```
class CreatEEView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView,):
    form_class =  ''
    template_name = ''
    success_url = ''

    def form_valid(self, form):
       instance = form.instance
       instance.created_by = Model.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
       instance.save()
       return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Try this `instance.created_by = self.request.user`

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow Instead of form_valid() method itself i need some other method

Comment: @mikan: why would you need another method?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My seniior developer suggests it is not the best place to set current user

Comment: @mikan: and why not?

Answer (score 5):

You should use `self.request.user` itself. Furthermore you should *not* save the `instance`, that will be handled by the `super().form_valid(form)` call, so:

```
class CreatEEView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = …
    template_name = …
    success_url = …

    def form_valid(self, form):
       form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
       return super().form_valid(form)
```

You could wrap this in a mixin, for example:

```
class SetUserMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):
    user_field = 'created_by'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        setattr(form.instance, self.user_field, self.request.user)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and then use the `SetUserMixin` with:

```
class CreatEEView(SetUserMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = …
    template_name = …
    success_url = …
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with something like this but it is not setting in the model.

admin.py

```
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.created_by = request.user
        print('********')
        print(obj.created_by)
        obj.save()
```

Comment: Even if you would use that in a form field, the Django form would not pick this up, and also makes it subject to request *forgery* where a user constructs a milicious POST request with a different user.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have edited the answer i have used this method in admin.py under modelAdmin it's not throught this method also

Comment: but here you are working with the modeladmin... whereas in your question you use a view...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes but before saving the data to model i am setting this in admin can't i do that?

Comment: no, a modeladmin is used for the admin site, it has nothing to do with views that alter that model...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sir Please suggest any method for adding  it to the form instead of view logic

Comment: this is not the place where one should write that logic, since a form is meant to validate and clean *user input*...